# How to apply filters in odata model read operation?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am trying to add filters in the odata model read operation. This is the [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read) where they have mentioned to pass it as parameters.

```
var a = new sap.ui.model.Filter({  
                 path: "Source",  
                 operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,  
                 value1: "Delhi, India"
          }); 

var b =new sap.ui.model.Filter({  
                 path: "Destination",  
                 operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,  
                 value1: "Kolkata, West Bengal, India"
          });  

var f = new Array();f.push(a);f.push(b);

this.getView().getModel().read("/Lanes", { filters : f},{
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("Carrier model setting up..");
            console.log(data);
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
              var mParameters = {
                filters : f, // your Filter Array
                success : function (oData, oResponse) {

                },
                error: function (oError) {

                }
              };

            this.getView().getModel().read("/Lanes",mParameters);
```